# Is there any way to add objects to a JComboBox and assign a String to be shown?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I want to add objects to a JComboBox but show a String on the JComboBox for each object.

For example, in the following html code

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

in the first item, the String that is shown is "Item 1", but the value of the item is "1".

Is there a form to do something like that with a JComboBox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding items to a JComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox)

Answer (score 5):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), in particular [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Basically, you want to define your object which will be contained within the combo box...

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public MyObject(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then create a custom `ListCellRenderer` that knows how to renderer it...

```
public class MyObjectListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                   JList list,
                                   Object value,
                                   int index,
                                   boolean isSelected,
                                   boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof MyObject) {
            value = ((MyObject)value).getName();
        }
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then populate you combo box and apply the cell renderer...

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
box.addItem(new MyObject(..., ...));
//...
box.setRenderer(new MyObjectListCellRenderer());
```

You could, equally, override the `toString` method of your object, but I tend to like to avoid this for display purposes, as I like the `toString` method to provide diagnostic information about the object, but that's me

Comment: +1. Besides the good reason given about not overriding `toString` method there's a really simple reason for not doing so: `toString` method can be overridden just once and therefore is a potential bottleneck. This fact is exemplified **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094845/item-in-jcombobox-instance-of-an-object/19096485#19096485)**.

Answer (score 2):

If your combo box model contains objects, their `toString()` method will be used by default to display them in the combo box. If the `toString()` method displays what you want, you don't have anything to do.

Otherwise, you just need to set a cell renderer to customize the way each object is displayed (and that doesn't limit you to text: you can also change the font, color, icon, etc.).

This is all described in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in the following html code

For something simple like this, where you have an "ID", "Value" type of data, I do like the approach of a custom Object who's purpose in life is to provide a custom toString() method. See [Combo Box With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for such an reusable object.

Many people in the forums do recommend a custom renderer. Unfortunately using a custom renderer breaks the default functionality of the comobo box. See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done using the object type as the parameter for the `JComboBox` generic, like this:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    // This will be the JComboBox's item class
    private static class Test {
        private Integer value;
        private String label;

        public Test(Integer value, String label) {
            this.setValue(value);
            this.setLabel(label);
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        // The "toString" method will be used by the JComboBox to generate the label for the item
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getLabel();
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFrame frmMain = new TestFrame();
        frmMain.setSize(300, 50);
        frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Here you declare a JComboBox that 
        // uses the type "Test" for item elements 
        JComboBox<Test> cmbCombo = new JComboBox<TestFrame.Test>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Add some elements for the combo 
            cmbCombo.addItem(new Test(i, String.format("This is the item %d", i + 1)));
        }

        // Listen to changes in the selection
        cmbCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox<Test> cmbCombo = (JComboBox<Test>) e.getSource();

                // The selected element is a "Test" instance, just cast it to the correct type
                Test test = (Test) cmbCombo.getSelectedItem();

                // Manipulate the selected object at will
                System.out.printf("The selected value is '%d'\n", test.getValue());
            }
        });

        frmMain.add(cmbCombo);
        frmMain.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```