# How can I accept a value to be passed, using a method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jlist

I am trying to select an item from the `jList` in one form (Home), and extract the data from the `ArrayList` and output the data to separate `jTextFields` in a different form (Details). Below is the method I'm trying to use to do this (not a lot there I know!).

```
public void passObjectData()
{
    int i = proObjList.getSelectedIndex();
}
```

I know once the method is complete, I can just call it on the form load method in the next form, but I'm stuck on how to get the method correct.

I don't know what other code, if any, will be needed for your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Please put `swing`, `jlist` and `jtextfield` tags back. Those are correct. @MarounMaroun

Comment: @dic19 I think the question is about passing values to methods in Java, which is irrelevant to Swing. If you think otherwise, please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I have a JavaSwing application, with many classes and many jFrame forms. I have hardcoded data into an ArrayList and have output a name to a jList. Now I want to get all of the data of one person that is stored in the ArrayList (name, address, tel num etc) and put this information into jTextFields. Easy if you are doing it in the same form! But I am not, the jTextFields are in a different form to the jList. So how can I use the .getSelectedIndex() function to select the item in the jList and display all related data to a different form with jTextFields?

Answer (score 2):

> *I have hardcoded data into an `ArrayList` and have output a name to a `jList`. Now I want to get all of the data of one person that is stored
>   in the `ArrayList` (name, address, tel num etc) and put this information
>   into jTextFields.*

As I understand your question this ArrayList is the undelying data structure used to fill the [ListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) and you want to get the selected index from the [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) to retrieve the correct object stored in that array list. In this case you can:

- Have a domain class called `Person` to hold the person's data (name, address, etc)
- Add `Person` objects to the [ListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html).
- Provide an appropriate [ListCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to display the person's name.
- Use [JList#getSelectedValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--) to get the selected `Person`.
- Pass this selected `Person` object to the text field's form and update those accordingly.
- Optional: attach a [ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to the [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) in order to listen for user's selection changes and do the previous step automatically.

See the first 3 points of this approach exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096485/1795530) (note: the example is using `JComboBox` but the same applies to `JList` as well).

#### Suggested readings

- [Creating a Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating)
- [Selecting Items in a List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection)
- [Writing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

#### Side note

Not sure if by forms you mean `JFrames` but just in case: please note that we should avoid using multiple `JFrames`. See this topic: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: hate those rulles here -1